# Issue with Bunifu Controls: UseSystemPasswordChar affecting Placeholder Text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, visual-studio-2022, bunifu

I'm encountering an unexpected behavior with Bunifu controls in my VB.NET application. Specifically, when I set the 'UseSystemPasswordChar' property to True for a Bunifu TextBox, it not only replaces the entered characters with the password character but also affects the placeholder text.

[image]

In the standard .NET TextBox, setting UseSystemPasswordChar to True only affects the entered characters, not the placeholder text. However, in Bunifu controls, it seems to be altering both.

Has anyone else experienced this issue, or is there a specific way to handle this behavior in Bunifu controls? I've checked the documentation, but it doesn't provide insights into this specific scenario.

Placeholder Text:
[image]

Comment: i Would subscribe to textChanged then if the text in the textbox longer then 0 set the PasswordChar if not then false.

Comment: I looked the documentation they Doing it by GotFocus or click event set the passwordchar = true. But they don't set it back to false after that.

Comment: Hi,@AeroSphinx. Is there any update to the question? Has your problem been solved? If the solution here is helpful to your problem, you could accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the text changed Event.

```
if(sender == null) return;
var BTextBox = (BunifuTextBox)sender;
if(BTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
{
    BTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
}
else
{
    BTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
}
```